# Woocommerce core changing external link protocol

Tags: http, ssl, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a Wordpress site in which I'm trying to add some external links to a footer widget. The site is ssl and I need the links to go to http sites. After putting these links in a text widget, they are being re-written on the front-end to be https.

I've isolated the problem to the Woocommerce core plugin, but I can't find any settings in the admin area (including the "Force SSL" setting) that fix it.

Does anyone know how to force the http protocol, or stop it from being changed to https? Ideally it wouldn't involve rewriting parts of WP or Woocommerce core.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Line 513 of woocommerce.php - had to remove 'widget_text' from the array of items that get filtered for the 'force_ssl' function.